# Android IAP : continueToken

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I am making a call to getPurchases

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                    itemType, continueToken);
```

1. What is continueToken here and what value to send?
2. I am getting empty list of RESPONSE_INAPP_ITEM_LIST, RESPONSE_INAPP_SIGNATURE_LIST and RESPONSE_INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST though I have lot of purchases (test purchases) for the item.

Comment: continuation token:  retrieve the next set of in-app products owned by the user. This is only set by the Google Play service if the number of products owned by the user is very large. When a continuation token is present in the response, you must make another call to getPurchases and pass in the continuation token that you received. The subsequent getPurchases call returns more purchases and possibly another continuation token.

Comment: I read this, but from where to get this token? Also I am getting list of items as null

Comment: I think its something that android internally will add if you read " the Google Play service". Try making the request without the token

Comment: I have got answers for point 2. If we consume product using Service.consumePurchase then the list returned will be empty.